# PowerApp Date formatting

Tags: date-time, powerapp

My company uses JD Edwards from Oracle and they store their dates internally as a 6 digit string in this format: CYYDDD where C denotes a century indicator (0 for 1900s and 1 for 2000s), YY denotes the 2 digit year, and DDD denotes the date as the number of days into the year. For example,

Jan  1, 2019  =  119001

Jan 15, 2019  =  119015

Feb  1, 2018  =  118032

Dec 31, 2017  =  117365

Is there a way to display the days as the number of days into the year? I'm not finding it.

Thanks,

gpence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no OOB function that I'm aware of. But perhaps you could calculate it based on the number of days since 12/31 of the previous year:

```
DateDiff(Date(Year(Today())-1,12,31),Today(),Days)
```